# Reg expression Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create regular expression for 2 specific numbers with hyphen between them which are going to be added in one input field.The numbers are 3-12 .
Any suggestions?

```
var reg = new RegExp('^\\d+$'); ?
```

Comment: Will you clarify the question?  are you looking for /^3-12$/?

Comment: What should be the correct number for giving the reg ex true;

Comment: This should give u some idea... bcoz i could not get ur complete ques...... var pattern = /^([0-9]+)*\-([0-9]+)$/;
var link = 3-12;
if(pattern.test(link)){
    
    alert('ok');
}else{
    
    alert('no');
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex literal is better in that situation. I think you are looking for:

```
var reg = /^3\-12$/;
```

When using regex literal (regular expression between two slashes) you don't need to escape every backslash.

Comment: Kamilkp thank you very much everything now is working.

Comment: @all A hyphen in a regular expression doesn't need escaping outside of a set but that's by the by... If you wanted to test for *"3-12"* literally use the `==` equality operator - even if you were looking for a specific substring you should be using [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).  Regex have their place but this is just stupid!